# How to display Special Price end date on front end

Tags: special-price

I would like to display the special price end date on the product and Categories pages.

Answer (score 4):

On Product detail page or Category list page, You can use following code to display special price end date.

```
<?php

// check if product has special
if($_product->getSpecialPrice()){
    // get special price
    echo $_product->getSpecialPrice();
    // get special end date 
    echo $_product->getSpecialToDate();

}
```

Comment: nice answer.....

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$pro = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(PRODUCT_ID);
echo $pro->getSpecialToDate();
```

Change `PRODUCT_ID` with id of product

For formatting date

```
$dt = $pro->getSpecialToDate();
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dt));
```